# Why C# PostMessage does not send VK_Return iff window is focused?

Tags: c#, windows, sendmessage, postmessage

I've been doing a program to send a text and enter key on a background running program , the `sendmessage (string)` works fine but after I call `postmessage(VK_ENTER)` it works only if the window is focused

here is code in C# (Visual Studio 2016)

```
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

    private static string SetText(IntPtr handle)
    {
        const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

        SendMessage(handle, 0x000C, 0, textSend);

        PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, IntPtr.Zero);


    }
```

Also I've tried with `Sendmessage` and it has the same result (the VK_RETURN isn't sent only if the window is not focused).

Comment: Are you really using Visual Studio 2016? :)

Comment: Visual Studio 2015* ,typo sorry

Comment: This is expected behaviour. As you've observed, any keypress is associated with the window that has focus. Windows would be pretty odd if it were otherwise. So, why not set focus to the window?

Comment: so there is no literally way of sending enter key (so another application like a messenger will send a message) without focus on it?

Comment: Why don't you use automation? Why the obsession with faking input I wonder?

Comment: Sorry but I might lack of knowledge , automation? is that a way to send keystroke to another window without it being focused?

and I am not obsessed with it but someone asked me to make it do that

Comment: UI Automation is a higher level infrastructure to automate applications. It doesn't rely on keyboard input, but rather invokes actions, regardless of input.